# Bitcoin Cash API similar to BlockCypher

Tags: bitcoin-cash, blockcypher

Is there any Bitcoin Cash API that has similar features as BlockCypher? Important is the ability to create new addresses and create transactions.

Answer (score 0):

> **Following are API’s, that provide wallet creation, transaction
>   management, withdrawing coin etc. Each one have their own
>   specifications.**

**https://block.io/docs/basic**

Widely used 
Multi signed i.e. Require two signatures for all withdrawals.
Currently we can trade only Bitcoin, Litecoin and Dogecoin.
We can create address
Send coins to other wallets as well as Withdraw coins etc
Get last/All/specific address transactions 
Good Documentation.

**https://accounts.blockcypher.com/**

Multi featured
Currently we can trade only Bitcoin, Litecoin and Dogecoin.
We can create address
Send coins to other wallets as well as Withdraw coins etc
Get last/All/specific address transactions 
Good Documentation
More Features avaible than above. i.e Analytics, events & hooks for notifications much more

**https://github.com/Overtorment/Cashier-BTC**

Self-hosted Node.js Bitcoin payment gateway.
Open Source & free.
Less Documented hence Hard to implement
No 3rd parties (works though Bitcoin Core node)
Transactions are signed locally. No private keys leak
How much coin we can trade: Working on it.
May be payable in future.
Battle-tested in production
SegWit compatible : Working on it.

**https://chain.com/**

Specially built for Financial services
Permissioned network access
Multi-signature accounts: Secure, multi-asset account management for individuals, businesses, and institutions
Instant settlement
Transaction privacy
Awesomely documented. 
How much coin we can trade: Working on it.

**https://github.com/bitpay/insight/**

Provided by well known BitPAy
Descent Documented
Multi-signature accounts: Secure, multi-asset account management for individuals, businesses, and institutions
Fees : Working on it.
How much coin we can trade: Working on it.
Secure

Answer (score 0):

You should check out https://www.bitgo.com it's great for Bitcoin, Bitcoin cash, etc. Great APIs. Make sure you review developer docs for v2 apis.

Answer (score 0):

blocktrail.com is nice but be careful as it'll be integrated into BTC.com